# calling function which reads data from .dat file

Tags: matlab

Warning: Direct access of structure fields returned by a function call (e.g.,
 call to INPU) is not allowed. See MATLAB 7.10 Release Notes, "Subscripting Into Function Return Values" for details.

> In Main at 3
>   ??? Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

Error in ==> Main at 3
INPU.m;

***getting this error...how to call this inpu.m file.***

my input file is below.
it reads data from dat file.
%---INPU.m----
%This file reads the input data from the file ‘‘'ex.dat'" and saves them in vector form

```
n=csvread('ex.dat',1,0,[1,0,1,0]);

constr=csvread('ex.dat',4,0,[4,0,4,(3*n-1)]);

q=csvread('ex.dat',7,0,[7,0,7,(3*(n+1)-1)]);

r=csvread('ex.dat',10,0,[10,0,10,(3*n-1)]);

x=csvread('ex.dat',13,0,[13,0,13,(3*n-1)]);

dx=csvread('ex.dat',16,0,[16,0,16,(3*n-1)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To call a function, you use it's name, *not* the filename (which has a `.m` file extension). The function name is the portion of the filename *without* the `.m`. In your case, since your function is saved in the file `INPU.m`, you just invoke it with `INPU`.